# Checking for files in only specific subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

In trying to find a way to check for files in directories, I found this:

```
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d /s "folderName\*" && (echo Files exist) || (echo No files found)
```

It works well enough except that I really need to be able to check in only half of the sub-directories that follow a specific naming convention.

[image]

Is there anyway to rework this line to only check in the "ToBeMoved" folders?

I tried writing it this way:

```
>nul 2>nul dir /a-d/b/s "\\SERVER\Path\*ToBeMoved" && (echo Files exist) || (echo No files found)
```

But it doesn't work. I'm guessing because its looking for folders at the user level with the string "ToBeMoved".

Comment: You could use a `FOR /D /R` command to get a list of the ToBeMoved directories and then check if the directory is empty or not.

Comment: Your first code cannot work as you describe unless you add the `/b` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first code you list is missing the `/b` option. Assuming it is actually there, then your original code lists the full path of every file within the directory hierarchy, but you direct the output to null, and conditionally take action depending on whether file(s) were found or not.

Instead of redirecting to null, you can simply pipe to `FIND`, logically looking for a path that contains `*ToBeMoved\`. That output can be redirected to null, and you can conditionally take action based on the `FIND` return code. I would ignore case when looking for the string.

```
dir /b /a-d /s "folderName" 2>nul|find /i "ToBeMoved\" >nul && (echo Files exist) || (echo No files found)
```

You could use `FINDSTR` instead, but then the backslash must be escaped

```
dir /b /a-d /s "folderName" 2>nul|findstr /i "ToBeMoved\\" >nul && (echo Files exist) || (echo No files found)
```

Comment: After doing some testing on this because its seemed to not work, I found that in a couple of subdirectories, a file called "Thumb.db" exists. It seems to be a hidden file, is there a way to have this ignore hidden files?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.  Change the root path of where you need to be with the PUSHD command.

```
@echo off

PUSHD "H:\users"
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /ad /b /s ToBeMoved') DO (
    pushd "%%~G"
    >nul 2>nul dir /a-d/b/s && (echo Files exist in %%~G) || (echo No files found in %%~G)
    popd
)
popd
pause
```

Output for me.

```
No files found in H:\users\johndoe\ToBeMoved
No files found in H:\users\maryjane\ToBeMoved
Files exist in H:\users\UserWithFiles\ToBeMoved
Press any key to continue . . .
```

EDIT: 
Just to show you that I do have a file in a folder named **ToBeMoved** I ran the dir cmd from the prompt. I only put one file in for testing.

```
H:\users>dir /a-d/b/s
H:\users\UserWithFiles\ToBeMoved\moveme.txt
```

Comment: I'm confused, I've never used the pushd function before. Where are you pointing the script to a specific directory tree? Is that the `H:\users" I replaced that with `\\SERVER\Path\Users\` and it didn't give me the same output at all. I got `Files not found Press any key to continue . . .`

Comment: @Neal Correct.  You put your root path in with the PUSHD command.  It can be a UNC path or a Drive letter with a path.  Sounds like you didn't test my exact code because you should have seen it echo **No files found in (folder path)**.

Comment: I copied and pasted it straight from the answer and replaced the path. I've checked it multiple times but I always get the same output.

Comment: Just incase its of value, "SERVER" and "Path" are above the "Users" directory from the structure image in the original question.

Comment: @Neal, not sure how to help you troubleshoot because you obviously can't show me the exact code you are using nor the exact make up of your server paths.  I can use the UNC path or the mapped drive letter and it works for me.  I have used that code plenty of times in batch file. I got that code from SO a few years ago.  I use this code all the time because I run hundreds of automation packages daily.  A few times a day the code runs to make sure there are not any files stuck in one of the folders.  They should be empty when the script runs.

Comment: @Neal,  You are a getting a **File Not Found** error.  That is coming from the DIR command.  That means it cannot find any folders named **ToBeMoved**.  Sorry.  That did not trigger in my mind right away.

Comment: @Neal, if you look at my example you can see that I am explicitly searching for a folder named **ToBeMoved**.  If the folder name is not exactly that name then you need to use a wildcard with the dir command. `dir /ad /b /s *ToBeMoved*`